# Dictionary stopping at loadingfromscreen

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, pageload

I run the code and it will not store the values it stops immediately at the loadingfromscreen.  What its supposed to do is a multi-page application form that will reinput the values to the texbox's on the back button from the next form.

The ASP.net code is too long to post, but basically its just texbox's and dropboxes. If needed i can post it, but the main issue im 90% sure is the C# code.

UPDATE: When i say stop it continues the code but will not run the dictionary method...i have put a arrow where the method stops in DICTIONARY ONLY

C#:

```
public partial class employment_driversapplication_personalinfo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> DriversApplicationData = (Dictionary<string, string>) Session["DriversApp"];

    try
    { 



            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadMemoryFromScreen(DriversApplicationData);
            }
            else
            {
                LoadScreenFromMemory(DriversApplicationData);
            }
              }

    catch //(Exception ex)
    {
       // throw new Exception("Exception occured in employment_driversapplication_personalinfo.aspx - Page_Load" + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {


    }
} 

private void LoadMemoryFromScreen(Dictionary<string, string> DicDriversApp)
    {

    DicDriversApp["position"] = position.Text; <---Stops here (won't even store this)
    DicDriversApp["fname"] = fname.Text;
    DicDriversApp["middleinitial"] = middleinitial.Text;
    DicDriversApp["lname"] = lname.Text;
    DicDriversApp["birthday"] = birthday.Text;
    DicDriversApp["proofofage"] = proofofage.SelectedValue;
    DicDriversApp["address"] = address.Text;
    DicDriversApp["city"] = city.Text;
    DicDriversApp["state"] = state.Text;
    DicDriversApp["email"] = email.Text;
    DicDriversApp["phone"] = phone.Text;
    DicDriversApp["altphone"] = altphone.Text;
    DicDriversApp["citizen"] = citizen.SelectedValue;
    DicDriversApp["whoreferred"] = whoreferred.Text;
    DicDriversApp["famfriend"] = famfriend.Text;
    DicDriversApp["relationship"] = relationship.Text;
    DicDriversApp["rateofpayexpected"] = rateofpayexpected.Text;
    DicDriversApp["rateofpaytype"] = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
    DicDriversApp["employedNow"] = employednow.SelectedValue;
    DicDriversApp["curremployment"] = curremployment.Text;
    DicDriversApp["pastAddress"] = pastaddress.SelectedValue;
    DicDriversApp["previousAddress"] = previousaddress.Text;
    DicDriversApp["previousCity"] = previouscity.Text;
    DicDriversApp["previousZip"] = previouszip.Text;
    DicDriversApp["previousState"] = previousstate.Text;
    DicDriversApp["previousDuration"] = previousduration.Text;
    DicDriversApp["previousAddress1"] = previousaddress1.Text;
    DicDriversApp["previousCity1"] = previouscity1.Text;
    DicDriversApp["previousZip1"] = previouszip1.Text;
    DicDriversApp["previousState1"] = previousstate1.Text;
    DicDriversApp["previousDuration1"] = previousduration1.Text;

    Session["DriversApp"] = DicDriversApp;
    }

private void LoadScreenFromMemory(Dictionary<string, string> DicDriversApp)
{
    position.Text = DicDriversApp["position"];
    fname.Text = DicDriversApp["fname"] ;
    middleinitial.Text = DicDriversApp["middleinitial"];
    lname.Text = DicDriversApp["lname"];
    birthday.Text = DicDriversApp["birthday"];
    proofofage.SelectedValue = DicDriversApp["proofofage"];
    address.Text = DicDriversApp["address"];
    city.Text = DicDriversApp["city"];
    state.Text = DicDriversApp["state"];
    email.Text = DicDriversApp["email"];
    phone.Text = DicDriversApp["phone"];
    altphone.Text = DicDriversApp["altphone"];
    citizen.SelectedValue = DicDriversApp["citizen"];
    whoreferred.Text = DicDriversApp["whoreferred"];
    famfriend.Text = DicDriversApp["famfriend"];
    relationship.Text = DicDriversApp["relationship"];
    rateofpayexpected.Text = DicDriversApp["rateofpayexpected"];
    RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = DicDriversApp["rateofpaytype"];
    employednow.SelectedValue = DicDriversApp["employedNow"];
    curremployment.Text = DicDriversApp["curremployment"];
    pastaddress.SelectedValue = DicDriversApp["pastAddress"];
    previousaddress.Text = DicDriversApp["previousAddress"];
    previouscity.Text = DicDriversApp["previousCity"];
    previouszip.Text = DicDriversApp["previousZip"];
    previousstate.Text = DicDriversApp["previousState"];
    previousduration.Text = DicDriversApp["previousDuration"];
    previousaddress1.Text = DicDriversApp["previousAddress1"];
    previouscity1.Text = DicDriversApp["previousCity1"];
    previouszip1.Text = DicDriversApp["previousZip1"];
    previousstate1.Text = DicDriversApp["previousState1"];
    previousduration1.Text = DicDriversApp["previousDuration1"];

}
```

Comment: Does "immediately stops" mean hang?  Crash?

Comment: Please show the code that assigns the dictionary to the session. I assume this simply never happens or happens *after* the call to `Page_Load`

Comment: Look at code and update on the post...i have updated the code that assigns the dictionary to the session is right above "LoadScreenFromMemory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
 private void LoadMemoryFromScreen()
    {    
     Dictionary<string, string> driver = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     driver.Add("position", position.Text);
     driver.Add("othervalue",value.Text); ///etc..
     Session["dict"] = driver;
    }
```

then, later on if you want to access the values in your dictionary, use something like this:

```
var dict = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["dict"];
```

problem with this is that you're going to have to use `dict.GetElementAt(index)` in order to retrieve values, and i don't think that's a very good approach.

This will work, but i kinda dont understand why you are using a dictionary to do this. I assume you are only loading data from 1 person on your page? Then you might as well just make a class with all the properties in it, and then you can just pass that around instead of using this dictionary/session hack.

```
public class DriversApplicationData
{
public string position {get;set;}
public string firstname {get;set;}
//etc
}
```

then, you can just do something like

```
DriversApplicationData data = new DriversApplicationData();
data.position = position.Text;
data.firstname = fname.Text;
```

this is gonna be alot easier to maintain and to retrieve/insert values.

Comment: so this will work when passing values from page to page? Cause the next page is their driving history form, so if they forgot something on the personal info page they can press a ASP back button on the driving history form and all their fields will still be there

Comment: when they press the "back" button in their browser the textboxes are going to be filled in still, but that's because of the viewstate in .NET

Comment: right i'm talking about not using the browser back button, just a button i create to make it more "form like" i mean i could make the back button just replicate the browser but i was hoping for something more secure than that...at the end of all the pages i will be submitting all this information to a SQL server

Comment: if you are going to insert this in a database then i *strongly* advise you to use the latter approach with the DriversApplicationData class. Dictionaries aren't used for this kind of thing at all.

Comment: alright so do the Public Class driversapplicationdata first then do the part under it to put exactly what i want...never used {get;set;} before

Comment: to put "exactly what you want" ? This is a place to ask questions, not to have someone write your code for you ;). If you just copy/paste my example you should get far enough.

Comment: hahaha thanks man, last question...should this go in the page load? and have the if(Page.Ispostback) so that it only does it when i click the next button?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17453/discussion-between-user1574685-and-thousand)